# Formatting the BASH command prompt

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to change the formatting on my BASH prompt from this:

```
anon@machinename.domain.poo:~/some/very/annoying/long/path$
```

to something like this:

```
anon@machinename.domain.poo:~/some/very/annoying/long/path
$
```

The idea is that I would be able to type a reasonably long command on one line without it wrapping to the next line so quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `\n` to your `PS1` definition, for example, to change the default colour prompt that is included in Debian do this

`PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\n\$ '`

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that on another SO thread.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following line, which you can place in your `~/.profile`

```
export PS1="\u@\h:\W\n\$"
```